# How to pass variable to url from the database, every-time a registration form is submitted

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm working on an online exam site. 
So when a user submits the registration form on my site, the user must be directed to 'url/accesscode'. Here, the accesscode variable must be sent to the URL from the database when the form is submitted. A new access code is to be sent for every new registration.

How can I accomplish this using javascript/PHP?

I tried to concatenate url using javascript, also tried hidden inputs on forms, but these will work for only single access code.

Method1 - Javascript

```
var aCode=“accesscode”
function onClick()
{
window.open("url"+aCode);
};
```

Method2 - HTML

```
<form action="URL" method="GET">
<input type="hidden" name="access_code" value="accesscode">
<?form>
```

Comment: You should fetch new access from database through ajax call inside you Onclick function.

Comment: could you please elaborate or direct me to links where I can know more?

Comment: Check [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp) link in order to make an ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a couple of functions, like `onclick`or `onsubmit`(form function), but there's too a way to do that trough the input using `onchange`or `onblur`, but you have to be beware about the behavior of each one.

Like:

`onclick` it'll be triggered when you click in the element.
`onblur` it'll be triggered every time the focus is out of the element (usually it used in input of `text` type).
`onchange` it'll be triggered every time the input is changing (when you filling it).

So following your sample of code the possibilities could be:

```
const element = document.getElementById('element');
const url = "something";
// using on change
element.onchange = function() {
    const form = document.getElementById("form");
    form.target.url = url;
}

// using onblur
element.onchange = function() {
    const form = document.getElementById("form");
    form.target.url = url;
}

// using on click
element.onclick = function() {
    const form = document.getElementById("form");
    form.target.url = url;
}
```

Now if you want to use in 'onsubmit' function you need referer the form element, like:

```
const form = document.getElementById("form");
const formUrl = "something";
form.onsubmit = function(event) {
   // if you want to prevent the default form behavior event.preventDefault();
   event.target.url = formUrl;
}
```

After that, you can follow your logic normal.

Comment: these functions will direct the form to the specified url, but how do I pass a variable to the URL when the form is submitted?

Comment: You do this in `onsubumit` method, it's on the answer, I guess you don't get the point, could explain in more details your question?

Comment: the submit function here will only call the URL, but it will not pass the access code to the URL

Comment: Please, look at the example, the example is `onsubmit`, go and read about the form functions, in on submit you can avoid the default behavior, can overwrite the url and do whatever you want in the form object scope, it's a pure javascript function.